# Ubuntu doesn't connect to VPN

Tags: vpn

I have a server in Finland, and i need to coonect to it via VPN.

[image: create new connection]

then I pressed "PPTP"

I filled in the inputs fields Gateway, User Name, and Password,
but Ubuntu doesn't connect to VPN, and shows me error "Connection Failed"

Comment: We all expected the error "connection failed" ... is there anything more which could help us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is really your VPN use PPTP or L2TP? I wonder it is L2TP and you must install L2TP packages/libraries.